# Convert csv files (from the same folder) to xlsx

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, export-to-excel

From one huge file i created a folder that stores different csv files based on `IDMember` value.

```
import os, glob
import pandas as pd

# reading the csv file 
df = pd.read_csv(r'path_of_my_dataframe')

# removing duplicates in IDMember column in order to identify with which ids we should be dealing (which ids are unique)

df1 = df['IDMember'].drop_duplicates(keep= 'first')

for elem in df1:
  df1= df.loc[df['IDMember'] == elem]
  #print (df1)
  df1.to_csv(str(elem)+".csv")
print ("CSVs  created!")
```

Next step is to create an excel from each one of this csv, i was trying something like this that is not working:

```
myFolder = r"path_where_i_want_to_extract_excel_files"

# Create a list to store all the csv files in the folder
os.chdir(myFolder)
csvList = glob.glob('*.csv')
print (csvList)

for elem in csvList:
  df_csv = pd.read_csv(elem)
  print(elem)
  df_csv.to_excel(str(elem)+".xlsx")
```

I have this error: "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xc7 in position 14: invalid continuation byte"

Comment: Microsoft Excel can handle CSV files. Is there a reason why you need to explicitly convert the file to XLSX ?

Comment: Yes, because i need to apply a conditional formatting for each one of the files

Comment: I made some changes in the last part of the script, but i have the error i wrote in the end.

Comment: where does the error occur, when you read the csv ?

Comment: The error occur when i try to write the excel file, in the last row.

Comment: Actually i solved the problem working directly with an excel file (the huge one, the first one) so applied `read_excel`  instead of `read_csv` and i created all the files i needed.